# How to achieve custom validations using directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to use directive for custom validation of the fields like for date of birth, "Date of birth should be at least 18 year" etc in my angular application.

For required field validation, I am using simple angular ways $error.required and $invalid.
For format validation, I have a directive where I check field type and then apply the regular expressions.

But I am not able to think a good way to handle the custom validations as explained above DOB case. I am currently using ng-blur and the methods are written in the controllers, which I think not the best way.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation and if this doesn't help I would suggest that you share your code.